# Increment Counter in CSS for a list with :before

Tags: html, css, increment, css-counter

I tried to increment a counter for a list with CSS. However, even though I can see the list numbers, those don't increment.

[image]

I used `:before` and the CSS property `counter`. Here's the code:

```css
.services__details--content__step>ul>li:before {
  content: counter(counter);
  counter-increment: counter;
  color: #0052ff;
  background-color: #e8effe;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="services__details--content__step">
  <h2 class="services__details--content__title">
    Les Étapes de la Création du Site
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Évaluation du Projet
      <p class="services__details--content__desc">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      Conception et Érgonomie UX
      <p class="services__details--content__desc">
        Took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic remaining.
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to increment the counter on the `li` themselves, not the `li:before` pseudo element. There is only one of those in each of their respective parents, so "counting" those will always result in 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the counter to 0 first. The only thing you need to do is add:

```css
body {
  /* Set "counter" to 0 */
  counter-reset: counter;
}
```

```css
.services__details--content__step>ul>li:before {
  content: counter(counter);
  counter-increment: counter;
  color: #0052ff;
  background-color: #e8effe;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

body {
  /* Set "counter" to 0 */
  counter-reset: counter;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="services__details--content__step">
  <h2 class="services__details--content__title">
    Les Étapes de la Création du Site
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Évaluation du Projet
      <p class="services__details--content__desc">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer.
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      Conception et Érgonomie UX
      <p class="services__details--content__desc">
        Took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic remaining.
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [`counter-reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset).

```css
body {
   counter-reset: counter;
}
```